# The term 'Get-MailboxFolderStatistics' is not recognized

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to get the first email a person SENT/RECEIVED, but I am getting a weird error message.  I was wondering if someone can help me with this.

1. I installed the module...
2. I connect to the exchange using my admin account.
3. I know I connected because the Get-Mailbox Mike01 works.
4. I tried using the Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics but it does not work.
   Any other module I should be installing?

I tried opening PS with administrator rights, but still the same

```
#Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline

Get-Mailbox Mike01
    
Get-Mailbox mike01@company.com | 
    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -IncludeOldestAndNewestItems | 
    ?{$_.OldestItemReceivedDate -ne $null} | 
    Select -Property OldestItemReceivedDate,Folderpath | 
    Sort -Property OldestItemReceivedDate
```

Comment: Your question says you used [Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-exomailboxfolderstatistics?view=exchange-ps), but in the code you use [Get-MailboxFolderStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxfolderstatistics?view=exchange-ps). which one is it?

Comment: I replaced Get-MailboxFolderStatistics for Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics

Comment: For Get-MailboxFolderStatistics you need module [ExchangePowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangePowerShell/0.11.0). For the `EXO` cmdlets you need module [ExchangeOnlineManagement](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangeOnlineManagement/2.0.5)

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I tried using the command in multiple computers, but it seems like it must be a permission issue.

Comment: Well, if you're getting error messages, please add these in full to your question. Perhaps these errors may shed some light on this.